# ExcelVBA - Converting from an array to a collection, then insertion of said collection into combobox list

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, combobox

I have Sheet1.ComboBox1 that I would like to fill with an array of values. This array is stored on Sheet2. This array is a list of all customers to be used in the excel file. All customers are listed in one single column.

Some customers appear more than once in the column. It varies by how many part numbers a customer has.

I would like to fill a Sheet1.ComboBox1 with this array, however, I don't want duplicate values.

I read online that I can convert the array into a collection which will automatically weed out duplicates.

I would like to take this collection and input it into the Sheet1.ComboBox1, however, upon some research, I've found that collections are read-only...(am I wrong in this conclusion?)

One strategy I saw was to convert the customer array into a collection and then back into a new simplified array. The hope is to store this new array into Sheet 3, then pull this array into ComboBox1.List. I've posted my code below of this attempt.

```
'Converts collection to an accessible array
  Function collectionToArray(c As Collection) As Variant()
    Dim a() As Variant: ReDim a(0 To c.Count - 1)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To c.Count
        a(i - 1) = c.item(i)
    Next
    collectionToArray = a
End Function

Sub PopulateComboBoxes()
Dim ComboBoxArray As New Collection, customer
Dim CustomerArray() As Variant
Dim newarray() As Variant
Dim i As Long

CustomerArray() = Sheet2.Range("A5:A2000")

On Error Resume Next
For Each customer In CustomerArray
    ComboBoxArray.Add customer, customer
Next
    newarray = collectionToArray(ComboBoxArray)
    Sheet3.Range("A1:A2000") = newarray


Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = Sheet3.Range("A1:2000")
```

I used ' CustomerArray() = Sheet2.Range("A5:2000") ' not because there are that many rows full of values in Sheet 2, rather, that I cover all bases when more customers are eventually added to the list. The total size of my Sheet 2 is currently A1:A110, but I want to future proof it.

When I run the code, the Array is successfully reduced and the new array is placed into Sheet3 with no duplicates. However, the first Customer entry is repeated after the last unique customer value is defined. (A46 is last unique customer, A47:A2000 its the same customer repeated)

Additionally, Sheet1.ComboBox1 remains empty.

Is anyone able to explain how to restrict the number of rows filled by 'collectionToArray' , instead of filling all 2000?

Also, where am I going wrong with filling the ComboBox1? Am I missing a command/function to cause the box to fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that function to make a New Array, seems Excessive to me.

- Assigning to `CustomerArray` will take care of Future Additions in column
- You can directly pass on the Collection value to `ComboBox`
- You are missing `On Error Goto 0` in your code after addition to Collection. That is making all to errors after that invisible and hard for you to identify which part of code is causing problems.

---

**Here Try this:**

```
Sub PopulateComboBoxes()

Dim ComboBoxArray As New Collection
Dim CustomerArray() As Variant
Dim newarray() As Variant
Dim i As Long


With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    CustomerArray = .Range("A5:A" & .Range("A5").End(xlDown).row).Value
End With

On Error Resume Next
For i = LBound(CustomerArray) To UBound(CustomerArray)
    ComboBoxArray.Add CustomerArray(i, 1), CustomerArray(i, 1)
Next
On Error GoTo 0

For Each Itm In ComboBoxArray
    Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1.AddItem Itm
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Being fairly new to VBA, I greatly appreciate the time each of you took to give me informative answers. I tried all 3 methods to try and better understand the code. I choose Mikku's simply because it was, well, most simple and it does the job.

The only thing that this answer is missing is an auto sort for when the ComboBoxArray values are added into the combobox. I added a command button to the sheet2 table so that when values are added, the editor can click the button putting all the table values into alphabetical order.

Comment: Glad it worked for you @rz ... Accept and upvote the answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should assign your range dynamically to CustomerArray...

```
With Sheet2
    CustomerArray() = .Range("A5:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
```

Then, you should disable error handling after you've finished adding the items to your collection.  Since you did not do so, it hid the fact that your range reference in assigning the values to your listbox was incorrect, and that you didn't use the Value property to assign them.  So you should disable the error handling...

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each customer In CustomerArray
    ComboBoxArray.Add customer, customer
Next
On Error GoTo 0
```

Then, when transferring newarray to your worksheet, you'll need to transpose the array...

```
Sheet3.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(newarray) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(newarray)
```

Then, as already mentioned, you should assign the items to your listbox with Sheet3.Range("A1:A2000").Value.  However, since newarray already contains a list of the items, you can simply assign newarray to your listbox...

```
Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = newarray
```

So the complete code would be as follows...

```
Sub PopulateComboBoxes()

    Dim ComboBoxArray As New Collection, customer As Variant
    Dim CustomerArray() As Variant
    Dim newarray() As Variant

    With Sheet2
        CustomerArray() = .Range("A5:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each customer In CustomerArray
        ComboBoxArray.Add customer, customer
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    newarray = collectionToArray(ComboBoxArray)

    Sheet3.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(newarray) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(newarray)

    Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = newarray

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be achieved in a number of ways. using collection or dictionary object. i am just presenting simple method without going through collection or dictionary since only 5000 rows is to be processed. it could be further shortened if used directly with combo box without using `OutArr`. As  @Domenic already answered it with explanations, may please go along with  that solution.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim InArr As Variant, OutArr() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, Cnt As Long
Dim have As Boolean
InArr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A5:A2000")
ReDim OutArr(1 To 1)
    Cnt = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(InArr, 1)
    If InArr(i, 1) <> "" Then
    have = False
        For j = 1 To UBound(OutArr, 1)
            If OutArr(j) = InArr(i, 1) Then
            have = True
            Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If have = False Then
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve OutArr(1 To Cnt)
        OutArr(Cnt) = InArr(i, 1)
        End If
    End If
    Next i

    Sheet3.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(OutArr)).Value = Application.Transpose(OutArr)
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear
    Sheet1.ComboBox1.List = OutArr
    Debug.Print Sheet1.ComboBox1.ListCount

End Sub
```